# Interfacing with Java from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

Is there anyway to interact with Java API from javascript?

Comment: Java on the client-side or JavaScript on the server-side?

Comment: Have a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

Comment: ...and *how* do you want to interact?

Comment: clarity required how u want clientside or server side

Comment: Javascript to Java application as an applet is possible and your question stays valid. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: @adarshr Since Java can be client (applet) or server (servlet/JSP) side, and JavaScript can be client (AJAX etc.) or server-side (running on IIS), and each can talk to both the others, the OP needs to clarify it for each language involved.

Comment: @AndrewThompson True. The OP just needs to open up :)

Comment: I've seen weird combination.... but Java excecuting Javascript, what's the benefit?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have made it with javax scripting framework which came with Java 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a possibility to call Java methods from within JavaScript - but that requires the Java-Code to be executed on the client in form of an applet.

For some sample code see here: [Call a Java method from Javascript](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html)